# Streamlit: (InvalidCharacterError) Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('td�') is not a valid name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have an HTML table:
When displaying the table, after ONLY activating "add_flag", it works fine.
When displaying the table, after ONLY activating "short_name", it works fine.
But if I activate both, it doesn't work. And I get this error:

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
> 'Document': The tag name provided ('td�') is not a valid name.

Anyone as any idea why?  Here's the full code:

```
def short_name(player):
    name = str(player['Player']).split()
    if len(name)>1:
        return name[0]+' '+name[-1]
    else:
        return name[0]

players['Player'] = players.apply(short_name, axis=1)

flag = {dictionary of the form "Name": "Flag Emoji" }

def add_flag(player):
    country = str(player['Country']).strip()
    country_plus_flag = flag.get(country, " ")
    return player['Player']+' '+country_plus_flag

players['Player'] = players.apply(add_flag, axis=1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `players.apply` correctly? To check that, create a test dataframe with 2 rows only, apply *short_name*, and print both the input dataframe and the resulting dataframe, and add it to your question.

Comment: Are you sure your data (in `players`) is correct (e.g. it doesn't contain invalid characters)? To check that, hardcode a constant `players` value (of only 2 players), and if it works, then you have broken data in `players`.